# Exit loop by entering blank line

Tags: c++

The loop is not breaking even after entering blank line.

```
string temp;
cin >> temp;
while (!temp.empty()) {
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
    cin>>temp;
}
```

When I don't give input and just press enter, it should exit the loop.Please help me.

Comment: if (input == ""){/* do things */} works for me

Comment: q may be uninitialized.
Anyway, the right tool to solve this problem is your debugger

Comment: Did you try to check "temp" value after you press just enter? I suspect that initialization to empty string before cin >> temp should help.

Answer (score 0):

try the `break` command
`continue` to skip current iteration of the loop

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer.

Comment: I want the user to enter the input till he enters a blank line.Please provide details.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` throws up `flag` `failbit` when there are no characters to read in from the `input` `stream`, and never continues on to try and `extract` characters from the `input` `stream`. You can achieve your goal with `getline( cin, temp )`. `getline()` reads up to the `deliminating` `character` in the `stream` and then discards it even if there were no other characters in the `stream`, leaving `temp` empty, and returning `0` from `temp.empty()`.

```
string temp;
getline( cin, temp );
while (!temp.empty()) {
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
    getline( cin, temp );
}
```

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/